# scala override java class method that references inner class

Tags: java, scala

If I have the following class defined in java

```
public class A
{
  protected class B
  {
  }

  protected void method(B b) {...}
}
```

And I want to inherit from it in scala and override method. I would have hoped to do the following:

```
class C extends A {

  override def method(b: B): Unit = {
    // ... do something
    super.method(b)
  }
}
```

However the scala compiler does not like when I do it this way giving the following error:

*method method overrides nothing. Note: the super classes of class C contain the following, non final members named method: protected[package ...] def method(x$1: A#B): Unit*

The only way I can make it work is to do the following:

```
class C extends A {

  override def method(b: A#B): Unit = {
    // ... do something
    super.method(b.asInstanceOf[this.B])
  }
}
```

I find having to do this quite ugly and was wondering if there was a neater way of doing it?

Thanks

Des

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious code works for me:

```
public class A {
  public class B {}
  protected void method(B b) {
    System.out.println("A#method");
  }
}

class C extends A {
  override def method(b: B): Unit = {
    println("C#method")
    super.method(b)
  }
}
```

Then in the sbt console:

```
scala> new C
res0: C = C@10ecc87a

scala> new res0.B
res1: res0.B = A$B@db9a93b

scala> res0.method(res1)
C#method A$B@db9a93b
A#method A$B@db9a93b
```

*However*, if I then modify C.scala and get sbt to do an incremental recompile, I get the error you see (tested with 0.12.4 and 0.13.0) – it might be worth filing a sbt bug about this.

Comment: The problem seems to be to do with it the compiler working from within eclipse. I tested it with sbt and it does work as expected as you have said - in fact it the changes I made for it to compile within eclipse don't work within an sbt compile. I will investigate further to try and find out the issue with eclipse.

Comment: I am guessing the problem is with the compiler as it happens from within eclipse also. Have reproduced with scala 2.9.2 and scala 2.10.1. So have filed a bug with the scala lang project.

Comment: [SI-7946](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7946), for those playing along at home.